# Adding object to array of LinkedList java

Tags: java, arrays, hash, linked-list, populate

So I'm working with hashing and want to create an array of LinkedList. How do you add the new Object to the LinkedList using the table[index]. This is what I have so far, but when I try to call the LinkedList method add it doesn't work. Is it because everything is set to null beforehand? Do I need to add everything manually?

```
private void populateLinkedList(LinkedList<String>[] table, ArrayList<String> dictionary){
    for(String s:dictionary){
        String temp=findHash(s);
        System.out.print(temp + ": ");
        int hashKey=hashFunction(temp);
        Anagram obj=new Anagram(s, temp, hashKey);
                    table[hashKey].add(obj);
    }       
}
```

`populateLinkedList(hashTable, dictionaryList);` This is how I call the function.

Comment: _"Is it because everything is set to null beforehand? Do I need to add everything manually?"_ ...probably.

Comment: `...when I try to call the LinkedList method add it doesn't work.` Do you get an exception of some type or what does it do to "not work?"

Comment: What is the type of `hashTable`?  There is no way to instantiate a `LinkedList<String>[]` so the method cannot be being passed the right parameter.

Comment: Are you receiving an `ArrayStoreException`?

Comment: @MattBall Your comment makes so much sense the OP is declaring `LinkedList<String>[] arr = null;` outside of the method.

Comment: @DoubleDouble I got the Array of LL working, and they are all set to null, but now when I try to addFirst(obj) I get a NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

An array cannot have a component type that is a parametrized type, or I should say its not useful.  Basically due to type erasure, the type of the array is not known, which causes the array store check to fail.

`LinkedList<String>[] table` is causing your issue.  The argument passed into the method cannot be of type `LinkedList<String>[]` because its impossible to instantiate such a type in Java.

Try the following line in your IDE, which won't compile:

```
LinkedList<String>[] list = new LinkedList<String>[];
```

Try using a:

`List<LinkedList<String>>` instead of `LinkedList<String>[]`

See the [Generic Faq](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20concrete%20instantiation%20of%20a%20parameterized%20type?)

### Working Example

I had to stub a bunch of methods, but here is a working example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArrayStoreCheck {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<LinkedList<Anagram>> lists = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Anagram>>();
        LinkedList<Anagram> anagrams = new LinkedList<Anagram>();
        lists.add(anagrams);

        List<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<String>();
        dictionary.add("one");
        dictionary.add("two");

        populateLinkedList(lists, dictionary);

        System.out.println(lists.get(0).get(0));
    }

    private static void populateLinkedList(List<LinkedList<Anagram>> table, List<String> dictionary){
        for(String s:dictionary){
            String temp=findHash(s);
            int hashKey=hashFunction(temp);
            Anagram obj=new Anagram(s, temp, hashKey);
            table.get(hashKey).add(obj);
        }       
    }

    //Stub
    private static String findHash(String s){
        return "";
    }

    //Stub
    private static int hashFunction(String s){
        return 0;
    }

    //Stub
    public static class Anagram{

        private String s;

        public Anagram(String s, String t, int key){
            this.s = s;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return s;
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: This compiles and runs fine for me: `LinkedList<String> strings = new LinkedList<String>();
            LinkedList<String>[] lists = new LinkedList[20];
            lists[0] = strings;

            strings.add("Hello");

            System.out.println(lists[0].get(0));`

Comment: Notice that you did not provide a type argument for the `LinkedList`, `LinkedList<String>[] lists = new LinkedList[20];`

Comment: His method doesn't compile but because he's attempting to add an Anagram to the list instead of a String.

Comment: @MadConan Here is the problem. I can insert any `LinkedList` into that array because the type information is lost at runtime.  See: https://gist.github.com/kmb385/7681956

Comment: My hunch is that the argument supplied for the parameter `LinkedList<String>[] table` points to a null reference.

Comment: @MadConan Your right also though, he is attempting to add an `Anagram` to a `List<String>`

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. It was because of the `<String>`

Comment: @kevorski Glad I could help!  Were you able to get everything to work?

Comment: @KevinBowersox What would cause it to not add the Anagram object to the null linkedlist in the array? If I look to see if it's null shouldn't it be able to add it? I get a nullpointerexception right now when I try to add

Comment: @kevorski If you instantiated the linked list like: `LinkedList<String>[] list = null;`  Its not going to work because there is no list, only a reference to `null`.  You probably found that `LinkedList<Anagram>[] list = new LinkedList<Anagram>[];` didn't work because Java won't allow that declaration.  You need to switch to the `List<LinkedList<String>>` as I have demonstrated in my working example, see the main method.  If you have further questions let me know and we can work through it.

Comment: @KevinBowersox will this add it as an Anagram Object and not a String Object?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42075/discussion-between-kevorski-and-kevin-bowersox)

Comment: @KevinBowersox So I got it working with an array of linkedlists, just have to fix my hash function `LinkedList<Anagram>[] list=new LinkedList[250000];` fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You really can't do

```
 int hashKey=hashFunction(temp);
 .... 
 table[hashKey].add(obj);
```

assuming the `hashKey` value is something that can be MIN to MAX integer value.  You can only access elements of an array with a value that is 0 to `array.length`.  What exception are you getting?

But I think the main problem is that you are attempting to add an `Anagram` type to the LinkedList which is expecting a `String`.

You definitely need to make sure there is an instance of LinkedList at any index you are attempting to access.